# PHP header ('Content-Type: image/png')

Tags: php

I have a problem with header in php.

I havet this simple code.

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I think it should works fine, but it didn't. There is no error, and in top-left corner of my browser a little crashed picture icon shows up.

I think header is the problem.

other useful infos:
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.8

**UPDATE**
In IE even if i have header, i got bunch of data...

Comment: you are suppressing errors with this line `@imagecreatetruecolor` are you sure that isn't creating an error?

Comment: Do ou have correct URL to this script in Your '<img>' tag? Try using Your browser's developer bar to see the complete http request and response.

Comment: My webserver has a log that shows me errors, and when i update the webpage there is no error. So i think imagecreatetruecolor is not the problem.

Answer (score 8):

For draw image in browser its have to send two headers before the main image data. First it is type of the data

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png'); 
//or
header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

and second it is data length. Without that header browser will be not know where the data ended.

```
header("Content-length: $size");   //$size image file size in bytes
```

need check php file have not any spaces and new lines before `<?php` and no php output before headers and image data output.

Answer (score 3):

The "little crashed picture" indicates that the image is invalid. Since your code to generate it seems valid, you must have a PHP error in there.

Comment out the `header` line, see what you get. If you get something that starts with `PNG` followed by a bunch of data, then you have a successful PNG image and you can uncomment the `header` line to see it. Otherwise, you may see a PHP error.

Comment: Remove the header and open the file in browser : you should see weird caracters but maybe (probably) the infringing warning...

Comment: I got PNG followed by a bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried, my problem was I didn't have the gd library. Once installed and set up, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct (tested) PHP code for obtaining and returning a favicon (just change the MIME content type for other images) is:

```
$c = file_get_contents($path,true);
$size = filesize($path);
header ('Content-Type: image/x-icon');
header ("Content-length: $size");
echo $c;
exit;
```

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is path of folder Create a folder for image

for example.: barla

After change your header header("Content-type: barla/image/png");

Your problem will solve

Answer (score -2):

Try with:

`header ('Content-type: image/png');`

instead of

`header ('Content-Type: image/png');`

And check the file encoding. It has to be ANSI.

Comment: header ('Content-type: image/png'); === header ('Content-type: image/png');